# Retrieve random value from an object's properties except for one value

Tags: swift

I have an object, and I want to pick a random value from it, except for the first value.  The code I am using is:

```
        algScramble.text = OLLScrambleData.DemoOLLScrambleList[selectedCases[scrambleNumber]].randomElement(scrambleNumber)
```

I know that `.randomElement(scrambleNumber)`is invalid.

`OLLScrambleData.DemoOLLScrambleList` is initialized with:

```
 init(id : Int, scramble1 : String, scramble2 : String, scramble3 : String, scramble4 : String, scramble5 : String, scramble6 : String, scramble7 : String, scramble8 : String){
```

I want to pick anything from `scramble1` to `scramble 8`, but not `id`.

How do I do this?

Comment: What about using a `lazy var` in `DemoOLLScrambleList`: `lazy var scambles: [String] = { return [scamble1, scramble2, etc.] }`, and do the random from there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know the question title asks how to pull the data out of a dictionary but the code you provided suggests that you are actually trying to interact with an object that has the scramble objects as properties:

> ```swift
> init(id : Int, scramble1 : String, scramble2 : String, scramble3 : String, scramble4 : String, scramble5 : String, scramble6 : String, scramble7 : String, scramble8 : String){
> ```

Feel free to let me know if I'm just misunderstanding your code but if this is the case, you could also do something like this:

```swift
func getRandom() -> String {
     int random = makeRandomNumber() // However you want to make a random number between 1 and 8
     switch random {
          case 1:
               return scramble1
          case 2:
               return scramble2
          ...
     }
}
```

Something else I would add is that if you are actually trying to keep ID in the same dictionary as the data you are trying to pick from, that might be a mistake that is holding you back. If you were to restructure the object you are trying to deal with to separate ID from the rest of the data since you don't want to treat it the same way, you could get rid of a big headache and make your code easier to understand and change.